# Selenium test fails to find the string

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a Capybara test which constantly fails when running on the CI server with the following error:

```
expected to find text "Mon, Wed, Fri from 12:00 to 15:30" in "Schedules Add a new schedule Everyday in 10:25 Mon, Wed, Fri from 12:00 to 15:30"(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

The line where it happens is a simple expectation:

```
expect(page).to have_content(content)
```

It seems very strange because it always passes on my computer.

Environment: Ubuntu, Jenkins, Rails 3.2, Firefox 26 with xvbf, Selenium, Capybara, RSpec.

Does anyone knows what can it be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1179. Maybe, it's the source of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Now it's pretty clear for me. Capybara doesn't wait for the content to appear on the page, but it happens at the moment between the search itself and generating an exception message. Ran it manually on the CI server having binding.pry before the expectation – it passes. So, all I need is to make Capybara wait a little bit.

Comment: I think this article may be useful: http://cabeca.github.io/blog/2013/06/16/waiting-for-completed-ajax-in-capybara-and-other-tricks/